# Nodejs Async database call doesnt worj even though function is defined as async

Tags: node.js

Can't understand why it doesnt work when the function is defined as a async function.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWcXX.png)

Help is very appreciated :))

Comment: first of all, past your code here.
second, what isnt working? what are you receiving?

Comment: Posted my code as a image :))
But iit instaly crashes because it says I used await in none async function, but I defined the function as async

Answer (score 1):

You are using `await` keyword in a function that isn't `async`. It is the callback for `jwt.verify()`:

```js
jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'), async (error, decoded) => {
  // ... code omitted
  const user = await User.findOne({id});
  // ... code omitted
});
```